# CSS how to select nav and li tags but exclude specified class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS block:

```
nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

How could I make it so that it applies to `nav` and `li` but not the class called `export`?  As it currently is, the styling is being applied to the `export` class because it is in a `nav` and an `li` tag.

Here is the corresponding HTML:

```
 </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="main menu">
      <ul class = button-container>
        <li>
          <i class="..." style="font-size:6em;" title="..."></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="..." style="font-size:6em;" title="..."></i>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="export button-container">
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:6em;" title="Export"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Add html code pls

Comment: plz provide ur html also

Comment: Lubos Voska, Rahul: Added relevant html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `nav li:not( .export ) {}`.

More on [`:not` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```css
nav li:not( .export ) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="export">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```

#### Edit

*- Example using markup OP added to question.*

Notice I simplified the CSS selector using the lowest amount of specificity to change the `li`. Unless `.export` appears on other elements or you have some other rule specifically targeting the `li`, you won't need the extra specificity that `nav ul:not( .export ) li` would provide.

```css
ul:not( .export ) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="other">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="export">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nav li:not(.export) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) css selector:

If `.export` class is applied to `li`:

```
nav li:not(.export) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

And in case if `.export` class is applied to `ul`:

```
nav ul:not(.export) li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
nav li:not(.export) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;
}
```